# Drag threshold aware dragging in Windows Forms

Tags: .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

Dragging from list and tree views has the nice property that it won't start dragging before you have moved the mouse a minimum distance - the drag threshold. The drag threshold is controlled by the SM_CXDRAG and SM_CYDRAG system metrics available in .NET windows forms through SystemInformation.DragSize.

If I want to implement a custom drag that respects the drag threshold, what is then the best way to do it? The documentation on MSDN seems to avoid that question altogether and just tells you to call DoDragDrop immediately on MouseDown.

Is there some event I have missed that can be used to detect when the mouse has been dragged a longer distance than the drag threshold? Am I really supposed to implement that myself for such a common thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, both TreeView and ListView have the ItemDrag event to tell you about it.  But that's not a standard event of the Control class, the events are specific to the class and is triggered by dedicated notifications generated by the underlying native Windows control.  Respectively TVN_BEGINDRAG and LVN_BEGINDRAG.  A few other common controls have it, header, toolbar and rebar.  Neither the messages nor the controls are "standard", they were added to Windows later, around the Windows 95 time frame.  Microsoft didn't add their capabilities to older controls.

So that's where the buck stops.  You'll need to implement your own on any other Control class.  It's not difficult with the MouseDown and MouseMove events.

Answer (score -1):

It would be fairly easy to implement a drag threshold. On mouse down, save the location of the cursor and call DoDragDrop, then in the drag event, check the distance between the mouse's current location and the saved location, and only move the element if the distance is greater than the threshold.

Comment: That is not what I'm asking for. I know how to implement it myself. Also your solution is wrong. DoDragDrop will start the dragging animation, which shouldn't happen before the mouse has moved more than the dragging threshold.